# Retrieve dynamically added element

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

The example is taken from [knockout tutorials - working with lists and collections](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections).

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th>
        <th>Meal</th>
        <th>Surcharge</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
```

`ReservationsViewModel()` adds a row of elements dynamically to a static `table` on button (Reserve another seat) click that is bound to `addSeat` with `click` event listener.

```
function ReservationsViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   ...        
   self.addSeat = function () {
       self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
   }
   ...
}
```

by calling `SeatReservation()`

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}
```

**How can I retrieve the added elements from DOM (not the clicked element) from within `SeatReservation()`**.

Edit: As far as I understand knockout's `foreach` binding, it repeats child elements. What I'm trying to achieve is, have access to those elements once they are added into DOM.

> **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4J3Pf/)**

Comment: hmm... does `new SeatReservation (...).meal` contain the element you are looking for? no sense in going to the dom if you have a reference to it

Comment: I dont think that _downvoter_ is the fastest reader on earth.

Comment: @KevinB it's bound to `foreach` loop. it loops through an array and then adds elements. Edit: I'm new to knockout, I dont know who to retrieve the element added. I dont want the whole element, I want the element which is added upon clicking "reserve another seat".

Comment: Which part loops over an array? guess i have to go to the jsfiddle to figure that out. though i don't think that's relevant to the question.

Comment: Where within your code do you wish to be able to retrieve the elements?

Comment: You're not really supposed to access the DOM. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @KevinB within `SeatReservation`.

Comment: @GôTô I need it for jQM for other purpose (DOM elemnet enhancement).

Comment: were you answering my second comment or third. it doesn't seem to make sense as an answer to either.

Comment: If you need to enhance it, the preferred way is to create a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), which gives you access to the DOM element

Comment: @GôTô check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6Z9xa/ check the difference between items added on load and items added by clicking "reserve another seat".

Comment: @KevinB I want to retrieve the element added within `SeatReservation()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a post-processing property such as `afterRender` in the `foreach` binding.

See Note 7 on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

The `afterRender` callback will need to be defined on your main view model, but since it is passed the current data item as a parameter, you can use this to call a function on `SeatReservation` and pass the DOM elements in.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: seats, afterRender: afterSeatRender }">

function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    // ...
    self.afterRender = function (elements) {
        $(elements).css('background-color', 'green');
    };
}

function ReservationsViewModel() {
    // ...
    self.afterSeatRender = function (elements, seat) {
        seat.afterRender(elements);
    };
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4J3Pf/2/

Having said that, the whole point of Knockout is to use data binding instead of manipulating the DOM directly. The Knockout documentation makes it clear that this is not a normal use case:

> These callbacks are only intended for triggering animations related to changes in a list.

In particular, manipulating the DOM within your `SeatReservation` view model is the wrong design. Try to keep your view models and your view rendering code separate.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. if I `console.log(elements)` in `self.afterSeatRender`, it returns `[text, tr, text]`. I want to retrieve _nodes / DOM elements_, is that possible? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y6XnP/

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Those _are_ the three native DOM elements that get inserted. I showed how to set the CSS background-color property on them as an example.

Answer (score 1):

With this [binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectmenu = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
        $(element).parent().trigger("create");
        //you can customize the code depending on valueAccessor and allBindings
        //here
    }    
}
```

Used like this:

```
<select data-bind="selectmenu: {option1: optFromModel1, option2: optFromModel2}, 
                   options: $root.availableMeals, 
                   value: meal, 
                   optionsText: 'mealName'"></select>
```

It [**works**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z9xa/2/) (and you can replace the `pagebeforecreate` with `ready`)

Source for the select menu update: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/no-style-to-dynamic-select-element

Comment: Thanks, however, note that `ready()` shouldn't be used in jQM and `.trigger("create")` is deprecated. I'll test your method.

Comment: Ok, what method did you want to use once you had the Dom element? I will update if you have a better way

Comment: I dont want to use separate bindings for each element, instead, I want to a retrieve those elements added. Each element type has a different enhancement method, that's the reason. I simply could use `.enhanceWithin()` on parent element, but I want to be able to access those elements once injected.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can have parameters in your binding if you need to customize for each element.

Comment: Once again thanks. You misunderstood me, I want to target each element, e.g. `select`, `input`, `button`, etc. So I assume the binding should be attached to parent container (element with foreach binding). Pls bear with me, I just started reading KO today :)

Comment: No problem. Why don't you want to add a different binding to each element type? It would be more "ko compliant" than accessing them from the parent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58673/discussion-between-omar-and-goto).